# Linear invariance of Newton's method for minimising a function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, newton-raphson

The question is from Question 4 from the following worksheet: http://cs229.stanford.edu/ps/ps1/ps1.pdf

It is a variant of this question: [Prove that Newton's Method is invariant under invertible linear transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605783/prove-that-newtons-method-is-invariant-under-invertible-linear-transformations?rq=1)

Newton's method for optimization can be expressed with the goal of minimising:

$$x= x- \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

or maximising:

$$x= x- \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}.$$

I am trying to show that Newton's method is invariant under linear reparameterisations, and I have managed to show it for maximising, but I am struggling to explicitly show it for minimising. (I'm sure it's acceptable to infer one from the other, but I don't want to do that.)

Let $x$ be some vector and $A\in\Re^{n\times n}$, and $g(z)=f(Az)$. We want to show that each iteration $i$ satisfies $z^{(i)} = A^{-1}x^{(i)}$.

**My attempt**

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x^{(i+1)} & = x^{(i)} - (\nabla g(x))^{-1}g(x) \\
& = x^{(i)} - (A^T\nabla f(Ax))^{-1}f(Ax) \\
& = x^{(i)} - (\nabla f(Ax))^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}f(Ax) \\
A^Tx^{(i+1)} & = A^Tx^{(i)} - (\nabla f(Ax))^{-1}f(Ax)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This is the point where I would hope to be concluding that Newton's method is linearly invariant, but I have $A^T$ where I want $A^{-1}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm new to linear algebra so I'm probably making some illegal operational.

Comment: What do you mean by linear reparametrization and what looks the invariance property like?

Comment: @mvw Question 4 on here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/ps/ps1/ps1.pdf

Comment: The property of invariance under linear reparameterisation pretty much says that an optimization problem (such as Newton's method) remains the same after linearly transforming the optimizing variable. So in this case, the optimizing variable is x, which undergoes the linear transformation under g(x) to f(Ax), and the optimizing method is Newton's.